# How to slow animations in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I watched a tutorial in unity and it had speed in the animator tab ,I don't seem to find it anywhere ,so how do i slow the animation [image]

Comment: I believe it is found in the Animator window, when selecting an animation.

Comment: Tap the triple dots in the Animation window and select *Show Sample Rate*.

Answer (score 0):

You can press on the 3 dots inside the animator window and set the sample rate i recommend 24 for pixel art games
[image]

[image]